# Zurb foundation font-size affecting row width

Tags: zurb-foundation, font-size

I'm setting up a new project with Zurb foundation.   I have a problem in that I want a couple of css classes to have different font-sizes to the rest of the site but doing that makes the row reduce it's width.

So

```
.boxed {
 font-size:0.8em; // or font-size:12px causes the same issue 
 }
<div class='row'>
 <div class='large-12 columns'>
  stuff goes here
 </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='row boxed'>
   More stuff here, smaller font-size
  </div>
</div>
```

The second row is a lot narrower than the first just because I've applied the .boxed class to it.

Any ideas on best practice for this in zurb foundation?

Many thanks

Comment: row dosent have width-it takes the space of the contents.so if you have smaller font-size or less padding-it takes less width

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?